# array-total-size-limit より大きなテキストファイルでパターマッチをしたい

Tags: common-lisp

common lisp の文字列は文字の配列なので、array-total-size-limitまでしか扱えないですが、これより大きいテキストファイルで複数行にわたるパターンマッチをしたいとき、どのようにするといいでしょうか?いい方法はないでしょうか?今考えているのは次の方法です。

1. ファイルを文字のリストにして、文字のリストに対するパターンマッチ
2. ファイルから適当なサイズの文字数を文字列としてバッファに読みこんで、文字列に対するパターンマッチ

Comment: 最近だと64ビット機も普通になりarray-total-size-limitも大抵60ビット近くありますが、マシンは32ビット機であることが前提なのでしょうか。
60ビット近くあると現在のコンピュータではこれを越えてメモリに全部読み込むというのは無いと思います。
* http://cl.cddddr.org/index.cgi?ARRAY-TOTAL-SIZE-LIMIT
array-total-size-limitの制限を越えるというのが重要なのでしょうか、それとも省メモリでパタンマッチするのが本題なのでしょうか。

Comment: すみません、マシンは32bit機です。clozure cl では array-total-size-limit が 2^24 程度だったと記憶しています。それ以上の文字数を読み込みたいのですが可能でしょうか?

Comment: 32bit機で2^24要素以上のデータを扱いたいということはout-of-coreなアルゴリズムを使うことを考えた方が良いと思います。文字のリストにしても1文字8バイト程度使いますから、たとえメモリに乗り切ったとしてもかなりきついと思います。で、「パターンマッチ」としてどういったものを考えているかで戦略が変わるので、そこをもう少し詳しく書いていただけると良いかと。

Comment: Cのコメント文をとりだして加工するようなことを考えています。最初は cl-ppcre でソース全部を読ませてから取り出そうとしていたのですが、非常に大きなソースの場合読みこめないですよね。